# Unexplained `kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled` with kotlin coroutines and spring WebClient?

Tags: spring, exception, kotlin, webclient, kotlin-coroutines

I have a bit of code written using kotlin coroutines

```
suspend fun getData(request: Request): Response {

        return try {
                webClient.post()
                        .uri(path)
                        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
                        .retrieve()
                        .awaitExchange()
                        .awaitBody<Response>()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error("failed", e)
            throw Exception("failed", e)
        }
    }
```

I am calling this bit of code like

```
 val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   client.getData(request)
}
```

In my logs i see this exception happening from time to time
`kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled` but this does not allow me to find what actually went wrong. I assume one of the suspending extension functions (awaitExchange or awaitBody) failed but i am not sure of that.

Comment: Try to enable stack recovery for exceptions within coroutines as described here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#stacktrace-recovery That might give you some better clue of what is going on.